# Convergence to a (unique?) fixed point?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, fixed-point-theorems, na.numerical-analysis

Consider a given $N\times P$ matrix $X$ (full rank with columns ${\bf x}_p$, $p=1,\ldots,P$), a given vector  ${\bf y}\in R^N$ and a thresholding function $\eta_\lambda(|x|)=(|x|-\lambda)_+$ with $\lambda>0$.

Start with a vector ${\boldsymbol \alpha \in R^P}$, define ${\bf r}_{-p}({\boldsymbol \alpha})={\bf y}-X {\boldsymbol \alpha}+ \alpha_p {\bf x}_p$, and define a sequence of vectors that changes only one entries to the current iterate, say the $p$th one, to
$$
\alpha_p^{\rm new} =\frac{{\bf r}_{-p}({\boldsymbol \alpha}^{\rm old})^{\rm T} {\bf x}_p}{ \|{\bf x}_p \|_2^2 } \left \{\frac{\eta_{\lambda}(|{\bf r}_{-p}({\boldsymbol \alpha}^{\rm old})^{\rm T} {\bf x}_p|)}{     |{\bf r}_{-p}({\boldsymbol \alpha}^{\rm old})^{\rm T} {\bf x}_p|}\right \}^\gamma.
$$
Repeat with a cycling rule, successively letting $p=1,2,\ldots, P, 1,2 \ldots$

Note that the case $\gamma=0$ amounts to solving the least squares problem
$$
\min_{\boldsymbol \alpha \in R^P} \| {\bf y}- X {\boldsymbol \alpha}\|_2^2,
$$
by a coordinate descent algorithm; also the case $\gamma=1$ amounts to solving the $\ell_1$-penalized least squares problem
$$
\min_{\boldsymbol \alpha \in R^P} \frac{1}{2}\| {\bf y}- X {\boldsymbol \alpha}\|_2^2 + \lambda \| {\boldsymbol \alpha}\|_1,
$$
by a coordinate descent algorithm. Fact: both algorithms converge to a unique point: the minimum of its corresponding optimization problem.

Questions: (1) For a given starting vector ${\boldsymbol \alpha}$, does the sequence converge to a fixed point for all $\gamma$'s? (2)  If so, is the fixed point unique (regardless of the starting vector)?